# Resource/Thread Allocation and Deadlock

Tags: multithreading, resources

Here is the question I'm having trouble with:

> Give the resource graph and determine whether a deadlock state results.  Assume that when a thread requests an available or unallocated resource, the OS immediately allocates that resource to the thread.

- There are three threads: T1, T2, T3
- There are three resources:  R1, R2, R3

Here is the sequence of events:

1. T1 requests R1
2. T1 requests R3
3. T2 requests R2
4. T2 requests R3
5. T3 requests R1"

Now, I have written out the graph for the problem.
[image: Allocation Question]

Have I drawn the graph appropriately?  Based off of this graph, I assume there is no deadlock because there are no cycles.  I am unsure if my solution is correct.  Can anyone help clarify this?  Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think there is no deadlock?  Can you expand on that?  What would an example of deadlock be?

Comment: I think that deadlock occurs only when there is a cycle in the graph.  However, I don't see any cycles in it.  I know that some threads are waiting for others to free up resources, but that shouldn't create a deadlock--if my assumptions are correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by cycle but you are correct about waiting for resources versus a deadlock.  So what would an example me of a deadlock using the resources?

Comment: Btw, I assume that the Rs and Ts aren't somehow connected, right?  It could be R4, R5, R6 instead of the same numbers as T1-3, right?

Comment: Here is a basic example that would demonstrate a deadlock:  T1 requests R1. T2 requests R2. T1 requests R2. T2 requests R1.  This would create a cycle in which each thread indefinitely waits for another thread to release a resource.  And yes, you are correct in your assumption.  The Rs and Ts operate independently, they are just arbitrary threads/resources.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  Deadlocks are all about multiple locks and lock order.

Comment: So, some other students are arguing that it is a deadlock.  I disagree.  Based on my clarification of deadlock and this example, would I be correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  This is not deadlock because T1 can still operate.  When it is done it will unlock R3 and T2 will get it.  It will unlock R1 and T3 will get it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It clarified my understand of thread allocation and deadlocks.

Comment: Cool.  I've added an answer as a summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize our conversation in the comments.

> Have I drawn the graph appropriately? Based off of this graph, I assume there is no deadlock because there are no cycles.

You are correct, your question does not show any deadlock conditions.

For me deadlock is not about "cycles" but about multiple locks and different lock order.  As you mention in your comments the following *is* deadlock because they each lock 2 locks in a different order.

> T1 requests R1. T2 requests R2. T1 requests R2. T2 requests R1.

Both `T1` and `T2` are blocking each other forever.  That is deadlock.

But in your OP, there is nothing stopping `T1` from finishing with the resources and unlocking them.  Then `T2` and `T3` will get their locks and everything will continue.  That is just lock contention.

Answer (score 1):

You have two processes accessing the same resource but a deadlock will not occur.

T2 is requesting R3. Since T1 is already 
using R3 T2 can wait or try again at a later time.

T3 requests R1 but can wait or try again later once T1 has finished. A deadlock would ONLY take place when t3 requests R1 and T1 has not released the lock because it is waiting for a process from T3 (which it wouldnt because it wants access to R1 first)

Comment: Neither of those is a deadlock.  That is just lock contention.

Answer (score 1):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/684/ploti.png/

here is how to make the graph, but you have to fix how many cycles the resources will be allocated and could they be allocated for two different threads.

deadlock happens when two threads request same resources and get mutually blocked.

Answer (score 0):

the problem reside in the allocations 4 and 5

```
4. T2 requests R3
5. T3 requests R1
```

you have to use a timelined graph (axis1 threads, axis2 cycles) and follow the evolution of the allocations in every cpu cycle.

Comment: Why is this a deadlock?